# bin/unet audio not works with ubuntu18.04

Tags: unetstack

When I ran the unetStack package in ubuntu18.04, an error was occurred. The error information is "Native library yoda_phy_pa_amd64 not found".

I have install the java environment correctly. And I saw the lib related to yoda_phy_pa_amd64 in unet3.0.0/lib dir named with libyoda_phy_pa_amd64.so. I copy the file to usr/lib and usr/local/lib, it still not works and show the same error information "Native library yoda_phy_pa_amd64 not found".

Install java environment, sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
Obtain the authority of the dir, sudo chmod 777 -R unet-3.0.0
Run the audio demo, bin/unet audio

I expect the audio demo will be work, and show the GUI in the browser. I have successfully run the demo in another computer with ubuntu16.04. But I don't know why it does not works.

Comment: Can you please try (re)installing portaudio in Ubuntu? And then try running `bin/unet audio`?

Comment: Your are right, I should have noticed that, thanks! I install the portaudio in the ubuntu system using the command, 'sudo apt-get install portaudio-dev'. Thanks again for your quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of a missing dependency for the native library that is used for UnetAudio. UnetAudio requires [portaudio](http://portaudio.com/) as a dependency.

You will need to install portaudio separately using `sudo apt-get install portaudio-dev` on Ubuntu or using MacPorts or Homebrew on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

This package worked for me!

```
    sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev python-pyaudio
```